# Cannot delete item in database and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables categories, products.  Products has foreign key category.  I am trying to delete (in views) through index.html.erb in products with below code:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category_product_path(product), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

however all this does is leave the following error:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/categories/product/products"
```

First, why am I getting this error, there is not a '/categories/product/products' url anywhere in routes or rake routes?  Below is the rake routes command (left out devise routes):

```
category_products GET    /categories/:category_id/products(.:format)                                              products#index
                      POST   /categories/:category_id/products(.:format)                                              products#create
 new_category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/new(.:format)                                          products#new
edit_category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/:id/edit(.:format)                                     products#edit
     category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#show
                      PATCH  /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#update
                      PUT    /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#update
                      DELETE /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#destroy
           categories GET    /categories(.:format)                                                                    categories#index
                      POST   /categories(.:format)                                                                    categories#create
         new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                                                                categories#new
        edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                                                           categories#edit
             category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#show
                      PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#update
                      PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#update
                      DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#destroy
       categories_new GET    /categories/new(.:format)                                                                categories#new
                      POST   /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#create
                      GET    /categories(.:format)                                                                    categories#index
                      DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#destroy
                      GET    /categories/:id/products/new(.:format)                                                   products#new
                      POST   /categories/:id/products/:id(.:format)                                                   products#create
                      GET    /categories/:id/products(.:format)                                                       products#index
                      DELETE /categories/:id/products/:id(.:format)                                                   products#destroy
```

EDIT:  This was solved by placing :

```
resources :categories do
  resources :products, shallow: true
end
```

in routes.rb, allowing only 'product' in the 'delete' link...

Comment: In `link_to 'Destroy', category_product_path(product)`, what is `product`?

Comment: Why do you have `GET /categories/:id/products/new` if you already defined a route as `GET /categories/:category_id/products/new`? Same for other 3 routes below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a nested route, you need to pass category id in the route. like:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', category_product_path(product, category_id: category.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Here, in the route `category_product_path(product, category_id: category.id)`, **category** is the category under which the **product** belongs.

You can also use `category_product_path(product, category_id: product.category.id)` as the delete route.

Comment: Could you post the current error message while using the above code?

Comment: It is exactly the same.

Comment: Answer edited. Try `category_product_path(product, category_id: product.category.id)`

Comment: I actually solved the url problem - using resources, shallow: true I am able to now just use 'product'!  Thank you.  However I now have a 'destroy' method error which I will post.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
resources :categories do
  resources :products, shallow: true
```

I was able to just use 'product' as the url/path

Comment: If you found a fix for your problem, consider adding it as an answer and **not** an _edit_ in the question itself.